# Increase file space in root

Tags: root

Fairly new install of Ubuntu-mate yet I keep getting low disk space warnings for my root partition.
When I select 'root' in my File System volume I cannot view the contents or get an accurate size.
Is there a good 3rd party utility that helps remove unneccesary files in your root to reclaim space?

here is a similar question asked 3 years agao
[How to free space in root directory and delete unnecessary kernel files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344504/how-to-free-space-in-root-directory-and-delete-unnecessary-kernel-files)

but I couldn't compile the Python utility and it is no longer being maintained.

Comment: please do a `df -h` and post the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 3rd party utilities to clear space in your root directory.

Run this command in a terminal to see how much space is available in your root directory:

```
df -h
```

Your root directory is the one designated as "/" in the column "Mounted on".

---

The easiest way to clear up some space is to remove the cached .deb files of applications you installed. This can be done in a terminal, as follows:

```
sudo apt clean
```

---

Now run df -h again in a terminal and see if it made significant changes to your space availability.

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean`